# Odoo 13: How to use Different weight UoM per company for same product

Tags: inventory, odoo-13

Can we use different weight UOM per company for single product?
for e.g pound for one company and kilogram for other company.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Odoo only allows the product to have 1 default UoM. Keep in mind you can set a different UoM within the sales/purchase orders itself. Therefore, mapping a default value depended on the supplier/customer selected can sort of realize a UoM per company.

> Purchase Unit of Measurements can be configured per supplier on one
>   product.

Within the sales/purchase order lines (within the form view), UoM default value can be defined with IF statements. IF product AND supplier are X then UoM = X. etc. You can use simple Python codes to do this. However, it's not waterproof and requires a lot of maintenance. Additionally, updates would override this code. It's easier for the users to just select the UoM manually when creating the order. Use multiple UoMs and refer them to eachother. (1 box > 12 bottles > 1 bottle = 1 liter etc.)

Working with packaging configuration could also solve quite a bit of your desires. Information/ideas can be found here: 
https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/question/multiple-uom-for-single-product-113506

Answer (score 0):

As Texie wrote before, per default, there is only one default weight uom.

You could solve this problem by coding a small module which adds a second field to the view and give the users the opportunity to enter their weight on one of these fields and convert the weight to the other unit by code.

The model file would look something like this:

```
class xyz_product_template(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.template'

weight_secondary = fields.Float(string='Second weight field')

# Here code where you convert your uoms of starting with @onchange
```

The view.xml has to be created as well:

```
<record id="product_template_extension_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.template.extension.form.view</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.template_normal_form_view" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="weight" position="after">
                    <field name="weight_secondary"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
```